# Loading data into specific columns in mysql table using text file in php

Tags: php, mysql

**This is my code** :

```
$query3="LOAD DATA INFILE 
        'C:/xampp/htdocs/schoolonweb/trainee/views/sliptest/sliptestuploads/$filename' 
        INTO TABLE $sliptesttable 
        (SchoolId,ClassId,SectionId,SubjectId,NewSubjectId,
        SlipTestId,StudentId,Mark) 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
```

And i am getting the following **error** :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' '' at line 1

Can anybody find where the error is ?

Comment: While getting data in file there is option field terminated by to select. You might have selected keyword other than ','. Check in your file what you have used to terminate field.

Comment: I have used ',' itelf.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax was incorrect. Try this one -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
  'C:/xampp/htdocs/schoolonweb/trainee/views/sliptest/sliptestuploads/$filename' 
  INTO TABLE $sliptesttable 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  (SchoolId,ClassId,SectionId,SubjectId,NewSubjectId, SlipTestId,StudentId,Mark)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the field declaration must come after the fields terminated by declaration:

```
$query3="LOAD DATA INFILE 
    'C:/xampp/htdocs/schoolonweb/trainee/views/sliptest/sliptestuploads/$filename' 
    INTO TABLE $sliptesttable 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     (SchoolId,ClassId,SectionId,SubjectId,NewSubjectId,
             SlipTestId,StudentId,Mark) ";
```

atleast in MySQL works in that way [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)